# Azure Publish settings

Tags: azure

Been trying to import my Azure publish settings file in visual studios. I clicked on Finish after browsing the file, but it waits for 2 seconds and nothing happens. I've tried it several times but can't see what exactly im doing wrong[Below is an image of where im struggling now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM7Pl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio i.e., MVC (.NET Framework) or Web Application (for .NET Core) also select `no authentication` then build the solution.

*Follow the below steps:*

1. Go to **Get publish profile** of your app service and save the profile locally like below:

[image]

2. Then open the ASP.NET project in Visual Studio, right-click the project in `Solution Explorer`, and select **Publish**.

The **Publish** pane appears if you have previously configured any publishing profiles. Click **New** or **Create new profile** to begin.

3. Select the option to import a profile.
   In the **Publish** dialog box, click **Import Profile**.

[image]

4. go to the location of the previously created `publish settings file`. Select the profile and click **Open**.
5. Click **Finish** and then **Publish**.

The deployment process gets started by Visual Studio, and the Output window shows the progress and results like below:

[image]

You can Click **Edit** to edit settings for any errors related to deployment. Change the settings and click **Validate** to test.